# Pass array to V8 function

Tags: c++, buffer, v8

I've started thinking of V8 for my C++ project, and I have a hard time wrapping my head around how data is passed from the C++ app to the V8 engine and back.

Below is some pseudo code, and I'd like to be able to define a global function called `doPocess` in JS that does some processing, only to be read back by the C++ app:

```
function doProcess(input, output){
    for (var i in input){
        var byte = input[i]
        output.push(byte)
    }
}
```

What could the C++ code look like in order to pass the array of data, and capture the output results?

Answer (score 0):

You can't expose a C++ array (say, an `int[]`) to JavaScript directly. Instead, you have (at least) the following options:

(1) You can allocate a JavaScript array (see the `Array` class in [v8.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/include/v8.h#4118)), copy over the data (converting each element to a JS value as appropriate), and pass that array as an argument to your JavaScript function. This will make array creation somewhat costly due to the copying.

(2) You can define an object with an indexed interceptor and an "embedder field", store the C++ array in the embedder field, and use the indexed interceptor to retrieve the elements as needed. This will make array elements accesses somewhat costly due to the interceptor.

(3) For purely numerical data, you can use a TypedArray, which gives you the option to share the backing store between C++ and JavaScript.

You can get the JavaScript function itself by reading it (by name) from the global object. For the output the same options apply (copying in the reverse direction for (1)).

Be sure to check out the [documentation](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) and the official [samples](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/).

Comment: Interesting. Very interesting. So a in my case, all I really want my app to do is to share two arrays of floats between C++ and V8, so TypedArray should be enough I'd assume.

I will absolutely have a look at the docs and samples.